# polymorphic lambda function not allowed

Tags: scala

I can't understand why this code is breaking.
The both methods differ in input parameters.

```
  object foo {
    def x: String => String = x => x
    def x: Option[String] => String = x => x.getOrElse("None")
  }
```

Compiler says `method x is defined twice; ...`
How can I work around this?
I would like to keep the lambda notation, so pipelining is easier when using the function.

Comment: After type erasure, both are basically just `Function[Object, Object]`. The best solution IMHO is to use different names.

Comment: both methods differ in input parameters. -- No they don't. They have the same input parameter, which is none. They both returns a function that differs in signature but both `x` are just a methods that takes no parameters

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by  "pipelining is easier"? There may be another solution to that problem.

Comment: @Tim: The following is the pipelining helper method I am using. So I can write e.g. ```f |> g``` to chain two function calls. it's easier for me to read, compared to ```g(f(...))``` : ```implicit class Pipelining[A](val a: A) extends AnyVal { def |>[B](f: A => B): B = f(a) }```

Comment: Polymorphism only applies to method invocation, and your code doesn't do any method invocation, it just calls functions. You can't have a value that is a polymorphic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this specific question becomes clearer if you add the brackets to the methods:

```
object foo {
  def x(): String => String = x => x
  def x(): Option[String] => String = x => x.getOrElse("None")
}
```

This makes it clear that the methods only differ by return type, and polymorphism (in Scala) relies on the argument types being different.

The broader issue here is that polymorphism only applies to method invocation. It is resolved at compile time, not run time, so you can't have a value that is a polymorphic function.

This is OK:

```
object foo {
  def poly(i: Int): Int = i
  def poly(s: String): String = s
}

val i = foo.poly(1)
val s = foo.poly("a")

val y: Int => Int = foo.poly
```

This is NOT OK, because it would require `x` to hold a polymorphic function type:

```
val x = foo.poly
```

(Also note that the last two lines involve the compiler performing eta expansion from method to function)

Answer (score 0):

Others have addressed why the prior code didn't work.  A possible work-around could be to create different instances of a type-class.  I recognize that this is likely a bit overkill, but since the question addresses using polymorphism - I don't see why using generic-based polymorphism couldn't be used to achieve the desired objective.

```
trait foo[A,F[_]]:
  def _x : F[A] => A

object foo:
  type Id[A] = A
  given foo[String, Id] with
    def _x : Id[String] => String = (t : String) => t
  given foo[String, Option] with
    def _x : Option[String] => String = (t : Option[String]) => t.getOrElse("None")
  
  def x[A,F[_]](using gv : foo[A,F]) = gv._x
  
@main def test =
  type Id[A] = A
  val f : Id[String] => String = foo.x
  val g : Option[String] => String = foo.x
  val s = "this is a test"
  val o1 = Option("this is a test")
  val o2 : Option[String] = None
  println(f(s))     // prints "this is a test"
  println(g(o1))    // prints "this is a test"
  println(g(o2))    // prints "None"
```